# Converting character array to float

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point

I'm trying to convert my character array data into float. Is it possible?

Code:

```
char str[5] = {'1', '2', '.', '3'}
void main(char str[])
{
    float var = (float)str[]; //error
}
```

This code didn't work. So I also tried using:

```
float var = (float) (str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3]); //output: 49
```

and also

```
float var = (float) (str[0] + str[1] + str[2] + str[3]); //output: 196
```

But they also did not work as expected..

My expected output should be `float var = 12.3`

Comment: Use [`std::stof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, how can I use that?

Comment: @SeeYahLater Check the link, it's well explained there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, using [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), which takes a C-string (i.e. a null-terminated character array) and gives you a float back (if possible):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   assert(argc >= 2);
   const float var = std::stof(argv[1]);
   std::cout << var << '\n';
}

// $ myProgram 12.3
// 12.3
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c77499ab59d8031))

<sup>Note that I have also corrected your `main` return type (which must be `int`), and I've gone with a more conventional set of function arguments: though their requirements are up to the implementation, [VS doesn't document any support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx) [for this unconventional variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88w63h9k.aspx).</sup>

Of course, you don't *need* the input to be from command line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   const std::string str = "12.3";
   // or `const std::string str   = {'1', '2', '.', '3'};
   // or `const char        str[] = {'1', '2', '.', '3', '\0'};

   const float var = std::stof(str);
   std::cout << var << '\n';
}

// $ myProgram
// 12.3
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc923c23eb0f5163))

Comment: Small point VS(2012) does happily accept the `void main(char str[])` signature, and I recall previous versions being happy with it too. But using the conventional approach is clearly the thing to do. :-)

Comment: @doctorlove: Thanks for the detail :) It seems to at least be [undocumented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx), though.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string str = {'1', '2', '.', '3'};
float var = std::stof(str);
```

Comment: I hate to fuss, but you have a missing semi colon on the 1st line.